# Live Agent for Mobile App built using Non SFDC SDK

Tags: mobile, liveagent

Can i customize UI for Chat window in Live Agent in mobile app that has been built using non Salesforce SDK.
Hybrid Mobile App will have API built for integrating with Salesforce Platform.